# highcharts solidgauge - make it striped or 3D

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization, gauge, donut-chart

I currently am using highcharts solid gauge to make donut charts.

[image]

I want the blue series to be 3D. I also want the green series to be 3D. How do I do this?

If this is not possible, then I want the red series to be striped, so that it is not solid.

Thank you for your help.

Please ignore the bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can research, it doesn't seem that you can apply the 3D settings to solid gauges.

You can do this for donut charts, however, as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/nxkv5woh/.

All I added here is the following code:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
```

This is the result:

[image]

As for your striped series, there is a Highcharts plug-in for pattern fills that might be helpful for you: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill.

If, however, you wanted to get a banded effect that looks like spokes on a wheel, you could probably achieve this with a "dummy" series of even-numbered data on a separate series, where each data point has the alternate color.

I hope this information is helpful.